# SearchDisplay controller is not showing my search results

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am trying to make a contacts tableview like the iPhone contacts module. I have a tableview sorted alphabetically with `header sections` (A-B-C-...). Now I want to search this `tableview`. After my search I should only have one section with all the search results.

The problem I have is that it keeps displaying `"No results"`. But when I look at the array in that holds my search results, it contains the correct values.

Now for the code.

My `CellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *kCellID = @"cellID";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellID];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kCellID];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView){
        NSLog(@"search tableview");

        Contact *contact = [self.filteredListContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",contact.name,contact.firstName];
        NSLog(@"CellForRowAtIndexPath contact text is %@",text);
        cell.textLabel.text = text;


        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];


    }else{
        NSLog(@"standaard tableview");
    NSString *alphabet = [firstIndex objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];

    //---get all states beginning with the letter---
    NSPredicate *predicate =
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name beginswith[c] %@",alphabet];
    NSArray *contacts = [listContent filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    Contact *contact = [contacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",contact.name,contact.firstName];
    cell.textLabel.text = text;


       [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
    }

    return cell;

}
```

Here is the problem. When I have in the IF this `self.searchDisplayController.isActive`  and I look at this log `NSLog(@"CellForRowAtIndexPath contact text is %@",text)`, then it gives me the correct name of the context. But when I change the if to this. `tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView` then it always goes the the ELSE part.

My `filterContentForSearchText`

```
   - (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
    {
        NSLog(@"filterContentForSearchText called");
        /*
         Update the filtered array based on the search text and scope.
         */

        [self.filteredListContent removeAllObjects]; // First clear the filtered array.

        /*
         Search the main list for products whose type matches the scope (if selected) and whose name matches searchText; add items that match to the filtered array.
         */
        for (Contact *contact in listContent)
        {
            NSString *searchString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",contact.name,contact.firstName];
            NSRange range = [searchString rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
                [self.filteredListContent addObject:contact];
                [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
            }
        }
        NSLog(@"filterd list: %@",[self.filteredListContent valueForKey:@"name"]);

        [self.tableView reloadData];

    }
```

This filtered list is filled up with the correct search results.

**EDIT**
Screenshot of storyboard

[image]

**EDIT search delegate methods**

```
#pragma mark - UISearchDisplayController Delegate Methods
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
    // Tells the table data source to reload when text changes
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:
     [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:
     [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    // Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption {
    // Tells the table data source to reload when scope bar selection changes
     [self filterContentForSearchText:self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text scope:
     [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:searchOption]];
    // Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: u use searchbar or textField for fillter ??

Comment: What is self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView and are you sure it is not nil?

Comment: @iPatel I think I use the textfield.

Comment: @borrrden I have added a SearchDisplayController to ViewController and connect it to this ViewController.

Comment: Try replacing the "if" with: `if (tableView != self.tableView){` . What happens?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a New Referencing Outlet connection to your Contacts Table View Controller.

When I placed two search display controller in one view controller. Only one search display works. And the good one has this Outlet connection. See my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539827/how-to-create-two-search-display-ipad).